# What optimisation approaches are there for the current for-loop in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, optimization, data.table

I have the following code that I would like to optimise, but I am currently not sure how I can do this. First of all, let me give you an introduction to the problem.

`test.data` contains approximately 200 000 rows, this makes the implementation below extremely slow in R. The first thing, I tried to do is to optimise the functions and remove as much as testing as possible (`if` statements), however I am unable to do this in two instances in the code below.

```
library(data.table)
test.data <- data.table(person = c("A", "B", "C"),
                        duration = c(120,50,30),
                        time = c(159, 231, 312),
                        savings = c(140000, 200000, 300000),
                        ren = c(0.0037, 0.0011, 0.0015),
                        res = c(55, 10, 30))

set.seed(35)

# Deduction series, note that in this example, they are arbitrary.
# They do not follow a pattern. I believe, this is the core of the problem.
# Which makes it extremely difficult to vectorise, since this would result in
# no closed solution.
c_a <- round(runif(max(test.data$duration)), 2) / 10

# Put in as a constant, but it can vary arbitrary.
c_b <- rep(round((8.5 / 12)/100, digits = 4), max(test.data$duration))
rnew <- 0.25
result <- matrix(0, nrow = 6, ncol = 120)

for(j in 1:nrow(test.data)){
  savings <- test.data$savings[j]
  duration <- test.data$duration[j]
  time <- test.data$time[j]
  res <- test.data$res[j]
  m <- matrix(nrow = 6, ncol = duration)

for(i in 1:duration){
  m[1,i] <- ifelse(i == 1, savings, m[6, i-1])

  m[2,i] <- -m[1,i] * c_a[i]

  m[3,i] <- -(m[1,i] + m[2,i]) * c_b[i]

  m[4,i] <- ifelse(i == duration, -(m[1,i] + m[2,i] + m[3,i]), -(m[1,i] + m[2,i]) / (time + 1 - i))

  if(i == res & res < time){
    m[5, i] <- -(m[1,i] + m[2,i]) * (1 - rnew)
  } else {
    m[5, i] <- 0
  }

  m[6, i] <- m[1,i] + m[2,i] + m[3,i] + m[4,i] + m[5,i]
}

  m <- cbind(m, matrix(0, ncol = ncol(result) - ncol(m), nrow = nrow(result)))

  result <- matrix(mapply(sum, result, m, MoreArgs=list(na.rm=T)),ncol=ncol(result))
}
```

Second, I have tried to vectorise the code, but I believe this is not doable, since `c_a` and `c_b` are random values and therefore, I can't simply raise things to a certain power. I believe in order to be able to vectorise the code, I need to be able to write a closed form function, but I am unable to do this.

Third problem I came across is the memory size, if I store all intermediate results in memory, that would explode everything into `3 * 120 * 6`, which is quite a significant memory increase in my opinion, so I am literally forced to do this "one at the time".

In addition, I have tried `%dopar%`, but unfortunately, memory constraints do not allow me to use more than 2 cores (16GB of memory).

Now I am wondering, what optimisation techniques further exists without going as deep as RCpp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach to calculate the sum of outstanding amount (i.e. OPs row 1 in result). All the intermediate values (`m[2,j]`, `m[3,j]`, `m[4,j]`, `m[5,j]`) can be calculated easily if required. Caveat: I did not time it with actual dim

```
library(data.table)

calcAmor <- function(ca, cb, rnew, dur, S0, tau, res) {
    amortize <- function(S, ca.t) S - ca.t[1L]*S - (1-ca.t[1L])*cb*S - (S - ca.t[1L]*S) / (tau + 1 - ca.t[2L])

    ans <- Reduce(amortize,
        split(cbind(ca, seq_along(ca)), seq_along(ca)),
        init=S0,
        accumulate=TRUE)[-(dur+1L)]

    ix <- min(res+1L, dur):dur
    tmp <- Reduce(amortize,
        split(cbind(ca[ix], ix), seq_along(ix)),
        init=amortize(ans[res], c(ca[res], res)) - (ans[res] - ans[res]*ca[res])*(1-rnew),
        accumulate=TRUE)
    ans[ix] <- tmp[-length(tmp)]    

    ans
}

set.seed(35)
test.data <- data.table(person = c("A", "B", "C"),
    duration = c(120,50,30),
    time = c(159, 231, 312),
    savings = c(140000, 200000, 300000),
    res = c(55, 10, 30))
maxd <- test.data[, max(duration)]
c_a <- round(runif(maxd), 2) / 10
rnew <- 0.25
cb <- round((8.5 / 12)/100, digits = 4)

test.data[, .(
        dur=seq_len(duration),
        S=calcAmor(ca=c_a[seq_len(duration)], cb, rnew, dur=duration, S0=savings, tau=time, res=res)),
    by=.(person)][, sum(S), by=.(dur)]
```

output:

```
     dur           V1
  1:   1 6.400000e+05
  2:   2 5.783318e+05
  3:   3 5.711966e+05
  4:   4 5.336450e+05
  5:   5 4.774502e+05
 ---                 
116: 116 7.075169e+00
117: 117 6.788631e+00
118: 118 6.339002e+00
119: 119 5.639335e+00
120: 120 5.297898e+00
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can suggest is to initialize `m` only once with the same dimensions as `result`,
and replace the last 2 lines of the outer loop as shown below.
This will avoid re-allocating* `m` and the element-wise `sum` done with `mapply`.

```
result <- matrix(0, nrow = 6, ncol = 120)
m <- result

for (j in 1:nrow(test.data)) {
  savings <- test.data$savings[j]
  duration <- test.data$duration[j]
  time <- test.data$time[j]
  res <- test.data$res[j]

  for (i in 1:duration) {
    m[1,i] <- ifelse(i == 1, savings, m[6, i-1])

    m[2,i] <- -m[1,i] * c_a[i]

    m[3,i] <- -(m[1,i] + m[2,i]) * c_b[i]

    m[4,i] <- ifelse(i == duration, -(m[1,i] + m[2,i] + m[3,i]), -(m[1,i] + m[2,i]) / (time + 1 - i))

    if (i == res & res < time) {
      m[5, i] <- -(m[1,i] + m[2,i]) * (1 - rnew)
    } else {
      m[5, i] <- 0
    }

    m[6, i] <- m[1,i] + m[2,i] + m[3,i] + m[4,i] + m[5,i]
  }

  result[, 1:duration] <- result[, 1:duration] + m[, 1:duration]
}
```

Your inner loop has complex dependencies on the results from previous iterations,
so I don't know if it can leverage vectorization of operations.

*Technically, R copies the matrix every time it's modified due to copy-on-modify semantics.
I believe that R does some special things with its memory management so that each copy doesn't necessarily equate to a new allocation of memory,
but the copy still represents overhead.
Since you're doing element-wise operations,
that may very well be your bottleneck,
and migrating to C or C++ with `Rcpp` might be your best bet.

Comment: Another possibility is to convert test.data to a matrix (drop the first column which you don't use). A matrix will process faster in the loops, but you will have to rewrite the code to specify the column number (or name with e.g. test.mat[, "duration"]).